# EXPLAIN "Rows" Jump When I Add ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, myisam

Thanks to MrCleanX for pointing me to the EXPLAIN function. (I deleted the other question on account of better phrasing here)... I'm basically getting a huge jump in "rows examined" when I add the ORDER BY clause to my query.

Tables:

packages and package_to_tag both running MyISAM

structured as follows:

**packages**  **date IS indexed**.

```
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   aid(primary) |     source       |   date(index)  |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   1            |    CA            |   2013-04-05   |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   2            |    FL            |   2013-05-05   |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   3            |    UT            |   2012-06-13   |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   4            |    VT            |   2011-04-29   |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
|   5            |    CT            |   2013-04-10   |
+----------------+------------------+----------------+
```

**package_to_tag** **unique index on package-tag** and **both package_aid and tag have indexes**

```
+---------------+------------------+
|  package_aid  |     tag          |
+---------------+------------------+
|   2           |    sports        |
+---------------+------------------+
|   2           |    nba           |
+---------------+------------------+
|   1           |    food          |
+---------------+------------------+
|   1           |    burrito       |
+---------------+------------------+
|   4           |    hockey        |
+---------------+------------------+
|   4           |    sports        |
+---------------+------------------+
|   3           |    news          |
+---------------+------------------+
|   5           |    sports        |
+---------------+------------------+
|   5           |    nba           |
+---------------+------------------+
```

My basic query is:

```
SELECT package_aid, source 
FROM package_to_tag
RIGHT JOIN packages ON packages.aid = package_to_tag.package_aid
WHERE tag IN("sports","nba")
GROUP BY package_aid
HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
ORDER BY date DESC
LIMIT 500;
```

Which if I "explain" gives shows me that I am examining every single record in the package_to_tag table (in the neighborhood of 1.5 mil).

However, if I take out the ORDER BY clause, this is reduced to a much more manageable 30k.

full result screen caps.

packages:
[image: packages]

package_to_tag:
[image: package_to_tag]

explain with ORDER BY:
[image: EXPLAIN w/ORDER BY]

explain without ORDER BY:
[image: EXPLAIN no/ORDER BY]

Indexes on package_to_tag:
[image: package_to_tag description]

How can I keep my sort without involving every row in the package_to_tag table?

Comment: add an index on date ?

Comment: I'll make it more clear above, there IS indeed an index on date.

Comment: Please give the full results of `DESCRIBE packages;`, `DESCRIBE package_to_tag;` and also the full result of the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`

Comment: try one on package_aid? and then on tag

Comment: @Sebas I added some screen caps.

Comment: what is the x_dups key? On what column is it?

Comment: @Sebas x_dups is a unique index for packages_aid-tag on the package_to_tag table.  I am preventing a package index from being associated to a tag more than once.

Comment: So you also have a key on tag by itself? Note that I don't see any date field in any of your tables.

Comment: @Sebas I do have an index on tag by itself.  Is that bad news?  Also, "date_added" is my date field.  I was simplifying with my table examples.

Comment: is TAG unique as well? It looks like it (`const`) That's pretty odd. Are you sure that x_dups is unique? It looks like `tag` is unique, but not `x_dups`

Comment: @Sebas tag shouldn't be unique.  I added a screen cap of the indexes for package_to_tag above.

Comment: could you please run the explain plan for that query with no order by clause, but with `GROUP BY package_aid DESC`?

Comment: @Sebas here you go: http://i.imgur.com/q1DLY77.png

Comment: the select is different, you added the unix_timestamp() in it. Was it like that all the time or is it a genuine difference?

Comment: @Sebas sorry... here it is without it.  basically the same result : http://i.imgur.com/MR1v9E2.png

Comment: good, I've got what I wanted.

Comment: But I'm really confused by the ref const you get without ordering by... Sorry, I tried my best. Last thing: try removing the limit clause, sometimes it really confuses the optimizer

Comment: @Sebas man, please don't apologize! I appreciate your efforts sincerely.

Comment: Also, brute force would be to add `FORCE INDEX(tag)` to the select clause. But that really should be the last resource...